# Cubic parametric curve rotation

Tags: curves, rotations, parametric

I am drawing a spline based parametric curve which is described with the following functions (U for horizontal axis and Y for vertical).

$$U = A_u+B_u*p +C_u*p^2+D_u*p^3\\V = A_v+B_v*p +C_v*p^2+D_v*p^3$$
$$$$
**How to rotate such a function $v(u)$ by $\theta$ degrees?**

$$$$
My output equation should be composed of powers of three at max. Many thanks in advance

PS. I have seen a video [How to Rotate any Curve by any Angle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BPgq2AudoEo&ab_channel=SenZen), but couldn't come up with a proper solution to my more complicated equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plane rotation is represented as

$$
R(\theta) = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos (\theta ) & -\sin (\theta ) \\
 \sin (\theta ) & \cos (\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and the rotated curve

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
U\\
V
\end{array}
\right)_{\theta} = R(\theta)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
U\\
V
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you! I also found this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310242/what-is-the-parametric-form-of-rotating-a-curve-around-the-x-y-z-axis and then I figured out that plane rotation is just a rotation around Z axis